# Proof check: a riemannian 2-manifold is orientable if its unit tagent bundle is principal

Tags: riemannian-geometry, surfaces, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, orientation

For a two-dimensional smooth manifold $M$ with a Riemannian metric, we can consider the unit tangent bundle $S\to M$, which is a circle bundle over $M$. I am trying to show that if $S\to M$ is a "principal" circle bundle, then $M$ must be orientable. Here is my try: Suppose $S\to M$ is a principal circle bundle. Then there is a right action of $S^1$ on $S$. Then we can define orientation on each tangent space of $M$ by declaring $\{v, v\cdot i\}$ to be a positive basis for any nonzero tangent vector $v$. This implies that $M$ is orientable.

Does my argument work?  I should show that the orientation on tangent spaces are well-defined (does not depend on the choice of $v$), but I got stuck showing this. Any hints?

Comment: The gist of your argument is good. For the technical points where you're stuck, you'll need local triviality of the unit circle bundle and the local expression for the principal action. Separately, what's your definition of _orientation_?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I meant orientation as a manifold.

Comment: Yes, but is that defined in terms of "overlap maps have positive Jacobian", "there exists a non-vanishing two-form", "the sheaf of local orientations has a global section", ...? :) (Any two definitions are equivalent, it's just that knowing your working definition may suggest a suitable idiom. But in any event, the main tool will be local triviality of the unit circle bundle.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I use the following definition of orientability of a manifold: An orientation of a manifold is a choice of an orientation (equivalence class of bases) of each tangent space such that it is locally represented by a continuous frame.  I know that this is equivalent to various conditions that you mentioned.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Does this approach apply? Extend the $S^1$ action on $S$ to a $\Bbb C$-action on the whole tangent bundle $TM$ by letting $v\cdot z = |v||z| (v/|v| \cdot z/|z|)$. Using this action we get an almost complex structure on $TM$ which implies that $M$ is orientable.

Comment: If you know existence of a complex structure implies orientability, yes, that's an elegant proof. (If that fact needs proof, however, it's essentially a restatement of your question. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thanks. But I just found that, for the extended $\Bbb C$-action, the mapping $v\mapsto v\cdot i$ may not be fiberwise linear.. Or not even an action because it may not be compatible with addition of complex numbers..

Comment: Ah, given the Riemannian setting I assumed too much. Still, the idea must be that for each unit tangent $v$, the group action compatibly selects one of the two unit tangents perpendicular to $v$. Maybe note that if $v^\perp$ is such a choice, the group action can be written $ve^{it}=\cos\theta_v(t)v + \sin\theta_v(t)v^\perp$ for some monotone function $\theta_v$, then impose "$\theta_v$ increasing" to select the sign of $v^\perp$ and show this choice defines an orientation.